# iOS/Xcode: Koloda framework: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, koloda

I am trying to implement this Koloda framework into my app. (https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda). However, when I run my app, I get an error in the line `kolodaView.delegate = self` which says "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

I have been trying to debug the code for hours but could not understand where a nil value is coming from. Here is my view controller file below:

```
import UIKit
import Koloda
import pop

private let numberOfCards: Int = 5
private let frameAnimationSpringBounciness: CGFloat = 9
private let frameAnimationSpringSpeed: CGFloat = 16
private let kolodaCountOfVisibleCards = 2
private let kolodaAlphaValueSemiTransparent: CGFloat = 0.1

class CardViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var kolodaView: CardView!
    //MARK: Lifecycle
    
    fileprivate var dataSource: [UIImage] = {
        var array: [UIImage] = []
        for index in 0..<numberOfCards {
            array.append(UIImage(named: "cards_\(index + 1)")!)
        }
        return array
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        kolodaView.alphaValueSemiTransparent = kolodaAlphaValueSemiTransparent
//        kolodaView.countOfVisibleCards = kolodaCountOfVisibleCards
        kolodaView.delegate = self
        kolodaView.dataSource = self
//        kolodaView.animator = BackgroundKolodaAnimator(koloda: kolodaView)
//        self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal
    }
    
    
//    //MARK: IBActions
//    @IBAction func leftButtonTapped() {
//        kolodaView?.swipe(.left)
//    }
//
//    @IBAction func rightButtonTapped() {
//        kolodaView?.swipe(.right)
//    }
//
//    @IBAction func undoButtonTapped() {
//        kolodaView?.revertAction()
//    }
}

//MARK: KolodaViewDelegate
extension CardViewController: KolodaViewDelegate {
    
    func kolodaDidRunOutOfCards(_ koloda: KolodaView) {
        kolodaView.resetCurrentCardIndex()
        kolodaView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, didSelectCardAt index: Int) {
        let myUrl = "https://yalantis.com/"
        if let url = URL(string: "\(myUrl)"), !url.absoluteString.isEmpty {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func kolodaShouldApplyAppearAnimation(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func kolodaShouldMoveBackgroundCard(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func kolodaShouldTransparentizeNextCard(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func koloda(kolodaBackgroundCardAnimation koloda: KolodaView) -> POPPropertyAnimation? {
        let animation = POPSpringAnimation(propertyNamed: kPOPViewFrame)
        animation?.springBounciness = frameAnimationSpringBounciness
        animation?.springSpeed = frameAnimationSpringSpeed
        return animation
    }
}

// MARK: KolodaViewDataSource
extension CardViewController: KolodaViewDataSource {
    
    func kolodaSpeedThatCardShouldDrag(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> DragSpeed {
        return .default
    }
    
    func kolodaNumberOfCards(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> Int {
        return numberOfCards
    }
    
    func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int) -> UIView {
        return UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cards_\(index + 1)"))
    }
    
//    func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardOverlayAt index: Int) -> OverlayView? {
//        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomOverlayView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? OverlayView
//    }
 }
```

If anyone could point out how `self.delegate` is returning nil, that would be appreciated.

Comment: did you make sure 'card view' is pointing to the correct delegate in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, card view is a class which returns a CGrect and creates a UIView in the storyboard. I have pictures "card_1, card_2, .." in Assets folder, and ideally the UIView in main.storyboard should display those cards and allow the user to swipe left or right on them.

Answer (score 0):

The error states clearly that something is nil and you can't force unwrap in this line:

```
kolodaView.delegate = self
```

Here, obviously only `kolodaView` can produce the crash. It means in the following line the connection to the storyboard was lost. Reconnect to the `kolodaView` in the storyboard in the following line.

```
@IBOutlet weak var kolodaView: CardView!
```